# Converting Prime Numbers from Base $10$ to Base $4$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It seems like when you convert a prime number from base $10$ to base $4$, the base $4$ number, when read back as a base $10$ number is also prime.

Example:

$13_{10} = 31_{4}$.

$31$ in base $10$ is prime.

Is this relationship always true? Why?

Comment: See OEIS sequence A065722, https://oeis.org/A065722

Answer (score 5):

It is not always true. For instance, $31_{10} = 133_4$, but $133_{10} = 7_{10} \cdot 19_{10}$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some reason it's true up until then but not further? Just curious.

Comment: @TC124 If you take a number base four and convert it to a number base 10, you always increase the number by a multiple of $6$. In particular, the base $4$ number is divisible by $2$ or $3$ if and only if the base $10$ number is divisible by $2$ or $3$. Now it's just a matter of the odds, and the fact that "most" non-primes are divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!